# How to create 3d chart (x,y,z axis) using jQuery or AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

I am using AngularJs with Kendo-UI chart controls, I need chart like below link (click below link), jQuery or Kendo-UI or AngularJs directive

http://asq.org/learn-about-quality/data-collection-analysis-tools/overview/doe-tutorial1.gif

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/3d-charts

Comment: Thanks you, have any open source (free version). Above link is free or paid license?